# A few iAd questions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

Hey everyone, I have a few questions about the iAd platform.  I'm not yet part of the Apple Developer Program, so please don't direct me to any Apple developer exclusive pages.

**1.** From what I've read, Apple charges $0.01 per impression and $2.00 per ad click, and developers get 60% of revenue.  Is this accurate?  It seems crazy to me.

**2.** Is it possible to have an iAd displayed only sometimes?  For example, only on the main menu/pause screen?  Is it feasible to do so?

**3.** iAds refresh every 3 minutes, right?  Does that mean that an ad can be clicked every 3 minutes for another  $2?  Just want to understand how everything works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Why does that seem crazy to you? Other ad agencies take a lot more than that. 60% revenue is actually a decent deal.
2. Sure, you can tell your controller only display the ad if certain conditions are right.
3. They refresh periodically, and different ads relate to different campaigns.

Comment: No, I mean the whole $0.01 per impression/$2.00 per click thing.  It seems too good to be true to me.  Good answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm not sure they've published any numbers. Those might be about right for "normal" adverts but there are also adverts from developers which are cheaper (and therefore net you less money). A bigger factor is the number of countries that iAds is available in. If most of your sales are outside the US, UK and a small number of other countries, your revenue will be zero.
2. iAd is a normal view that you can add where and when you like.
3. I don't think so. Last I checked you need to refresh them "manually." Apple warn against refreshing more than every thirty seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated iAd into my app four days ago. I have about 300 users and I've made nearly $50 already. Granted I probably sat there for ten minutes and clicked the ads. :p I'm not sure if it helps with anything, but I recommend it if you don't have many users. It can be an okay source of revenue, especially if you have a lot of users in your app, or if you have multiple apps running iAd. Sorry to bring back such an old question.